# Trentrichardson's Jquery datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, html, datetimepicker

I found something that fits the requirements of Date Time Picker but It doesnt work on the fly. Anyone tried using trentrichardson's jquery date time picker?

[image: trentrichardson's jquery date time picker]

html code goes like this

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dark-hive/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css"/ >
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jvs.js"></script>
<script>
$('#dateField').datetimepicker({
  controlType: 'select',
  timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input name="StartTime" type="text" required placeholder="StartTime" id="dateField"><br>
</body>
```

And it doesnt show up..

Comment: Try wrapping your js code in `$(document).ready()` Also, you need to include jQuery reference

Comment: I did $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#hizukeJikanHenkou').datetimepicker({
  controlType: 'select',
  timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
});
  }); but still, what do you mean with jQuery reference?

Comment: `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`, a reference to jQuery library.

Comment: Oh I see, the other pages I developed that uses jquery datepicker doesnt have this and works fine anyway Thanks!